# Are there alternative data structures than array in PHP, where I can benefit from different index techniques?

Tags: php, arrays, tree, indexing, hashmap

Lately I had an issue with an array that contained some hundred thousands of values and the only thing I wanted to do was to check whether a value was already present.
In my case this were IPs from a webserver log.
So basically something like:

`in_array(ip2long(ip),$myarray)` did the job

However the lookup time increased dramatically and 10k of lookups took around 17 seconds or so.

So in this case I didn't care whether I had duplicates or not, I just needed to check for existence. So I could store the IPs in the index like this:

```
isset($myarray[ip2long($ip)])
```

And boom, lookup times went down from 17 seconds (and more) to a static time of 0.8 seconds for 10k lookups. As a value for the array entry I just used `int 1`.

I think the array index is probably based on some b-tree which should have log(n) lookup time and the index on a hashmap.

In my case using the index worked fine, but are there any data structures where I can use hashmaps as a value index, where multiple values may also occour (i realize that this makes only sense if do not have too many duplicates and I cannot use range/search requests efficiently, which is the primary benefit of tree structures)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a whole range of alternatives datastructures beyond simple arrays in the [SPL library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) bundled with PHP, including linked lists, stacks, heaps, queues, etc.

However, I suspect you could make your logic a whole lot more efficient if you [flipped](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) your array, allowing you to do a lookup on the key (using the [array_key_exists()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) function) rather than search for the value. The array index is a hash, rather than a btree, making for very fast direct access via the key.

However, if you're working with 10k entries in an array, you'd probably be better taking advantage of a database, where you can define your own indexes.

Comment: Sometimes good solutions are right in front of you and you just think too complicated. -- Nicely done.

Comment: He flipped it from what I understand.

Comment: Using isset($a[$key]) is much (!) faster than array_key_exists($key, $a), because isset is a structure and array_key_exists() is a function.

Answer (score 2):

You also have the [chdb](http://php.net/manual/en/class.chdb.php) (constant hash database) extension - which is perfect for this.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays have an sequential order and it's quick to access certain elements, because you don't need to traverse a tree or work through a sequential list structure.

A set is of course faster here, because you only check unique elements and not all elements (in the array).

Tree's are fine for in example sorted structures. You could implement a tree with IPs sorted by their ranges, then you could decide faster if this IP exist or not.
I'm not sure if PHP provides such customised tree structures. I guess you'll need to implement this yourself, but this will take about half an hour.

You'll find sample codes on the web for such tree structures.

Answer (score 1):

as already answered, you can use brand new classes provided by spl http://www.php.net/spl

BUT apparently they are not as fast as people think. probably they are not implemented as we expect. it is my opinion that splfixedarray, for example, is not a real array, but a hashtable as classic php's arrays

BUT also, you have some alternative solutions

first you can store your result in a database. queries are fast because db indexes may be better optimized than a php datastructure

you can use http://www.php.net/sqlite3 and store results in a temporary database (a file or in memory)

I suggest a temporary file, because you don't have to load all in memory, and in plus you can add each row individually (using http://www.php.net/fgets for example)

HTH!

feel free to correct my English